# C++ OpenGL triangles seem to adress wrong vertex

Tags: c++, opengl, buffer, vertex

I'm trying to create a cube using OpenGL. When calling only one of the functions to build a cube side it works. But when draw multible sides the triangles seem to address the wrong vertex. Do you know what I made wrong?

CubeCreator.cpp

```
#include "../headers/CubeCreator.h"

CubeCreator::CubeCreator(float voxelSize) {
    this->voxelSize = voxelSize;
}

void CubeCreator::addVertex(glm::vec3 position, glm::vec3 color)
{
    Vertex vertex;
    vertex.position = position;
    vertex.color = color;
    vertices.push_back(vertex);
}

void CubeCreator::addVertices(float verts[8], glm::vec3 color)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i+=3)
    {
        addVertex(glm::vec3(verts[i], verts[i+1], verts[i+2]), color);
    }
}

void CubeCreator::addTriangles(GLuint tris[6])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        triangles.push_back(triangleCount+tris[i]);
    }
    triangleCount += 6;
}

void CubeCreator::left(glm::vec3 position, glm::vec3 color)
{
    float verts[12] =
    {
        position.x,             position.y,             position.z - voxelSize,
        position.x,             position.y,             position.z,
        position.x,             position.y + voxelSize, position.z,
        position.x,             position.y + voxelSize, position.z - voxelSize
    }; addVertices(verts, color);
    GLuint tris[6] =
    {
        0, 1, 3,
        1, 2, 3
    }; addTriangles(tris);
}

void CubeCreator::right(glm::vec3 position, glm::vec3 color)
{
    float verts[12] =
    {
        position.x + voxelSize,             position.y,             position.z,
        position.x + voxelSize,             position.y,             position.z - voxelSize,
        position.x + voxelSize,             position.y + voxelSize, position.z - voxelSize,
        position.x + voxelSize,             position.y + voxelSize
    }; addVertices(verts, color);
    GLuint tris[6] =
    {
        0, 1, 3,
        1, 2, 3
    }; addTriangles(tris);
}

void CubeCreator::back(glm::vec3 position, glm::vec3 color)
{
    float verts[12] =
    {
        position.x,             position.y,             position.z,
        position.x + voxelSize, position.y,             position.z,
        position.x + voxelSize, position.y + voxelSize, position.z,
        position.x,             position.y + voxelSize, position.z
    }; addVertices(verts, color);
    GLuint tris[6] =
    {
        0, 1, 3,
        1, 2, 3
    }; addTriangles(tris);
}

Mesh CubeCreator::getMesh() {
    Mesh mesh(vertices, triangles);
    return mesh;
}
```

Mesh.cpp

```
#include "../headers/Mesh.h"

Mesh::Mesh(vector<Vertex> vertices, vector<GLuint> triangles)
{
    this->vertices  = vertices;
    this->triangles = triangles;

    this->init();
}

void Mesh::init() {
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &this->VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &this->VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &this->EBO);

    glBindVertexArray(this->VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->EBO);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                 this->vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex),
                 &this->vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                 this->triangles.size() * sizeof(GLuint),
                 &this->triangles[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0,
                          3,
                          GL_FLOAT,
                          GL_FALSE,
                          sizeof(Vertex),
                          (GLvoid*)0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1,
                          3,
                          GL_FLOAT,
                          GL_FALSE,
                          sizeof(Vertex),
                          (GLvoid*)offsetof(Vertex, color));
}

void Mesh::draw() {
    glBindVertexArray(this->VAO);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, this->triangles.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

main.cpp

```
CubeCreator cubeCreator(1.0f);
    cubeCreator.left(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    cubeCreator.right(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
```

I know that's a lot of code but I don't know in which part the error is!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know how your `addTriangles()` function works, but I suspect that it does not take into account that the index data has to be offseted if other vertices are already in the buffer. If you did add the first side, you will have 6 indices in the array, and the vertex 0 of the second face will be index 7, and so on.

Comment: That's why I'm calling triangleCount += 6

Comment: Yeah. and that's the error. And I made the same one in my comment. There are only 4 vertices per face, so you have to increas it by four, not by 6.

Comment: Thank you! That was the mistake!